# How do I get my function inside a map to return a value instead of a Promise pending?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, async-await, promise

I am using Node.js (I am at beginners level) and Google Cloud Firestore and I am having issues with having my map function to wait for my `getStuff()`-function, and will instead return a Promise rather than the value/text itself.

I have two functions like this:

```
function getUserData() {
   return db.collection('users').get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
            var docs = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => [doc.data(), doc.id, getStuff(doc.id)])
            console.log(docs)
            return docs                          
        });
}

function getStuff(doc_id) {
   return db.collection('users').doc(doc_id).collection('tweets').limit(1).get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
            var docs = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());         
            console.log("TWEETS", doc_id, docs[0]['text']);
            return docs[0]['text']
        });   
}
```

The `getStuff()` function produces a console log result as:

```
TWEETS DAU86mxIhmD6qQQpH4F God’s country!
TWEETS JQHTO0jUjAodMQMR6wI I’m almost there Danny!
```

whereas the `console.log(docs)` in `getUserData()` returns:

```
  [
    {
      name: "John McClane",
      twitter: 'john4'
    },
    'Yn4rEotMR02jEQSqdV4',
    Promise { <pending> } // <- This is where the tweet should have been
  ]
```

I am not to familiar with Promises and await/async and I can't get that to work. How do I set up my getUserData-function so that it will provide the Tweet text and not a Promise { pending }?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since `getStuff()` returns a promise you need to await it to resolve.

```
    async function getUserData() {
       return db.collection('users').get()
            .then((querySnapshot) => {
                var promises = querySnapshot.docs.map(async doc => {
                      var stuff = await getStuff(doc.id)
                      return [doc.data(), doc.id, stuff]
                })
               var docs =  await Promise.all(promises)
                console.log(docs)
                return docs                          
            });
    }
```

Comment: This seems logically perfectly correct but when I do this I get the error: "SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules" for the line "var docs = await Promise.all(promises)". Just by trial and error I have seen this error appear quite often. How do I resolve that?

Comment: I solved it by just removing the "await" on that line. This works! THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

the `getStuff()` function returns a promise. one ways to resolve the promise is to use await.

Call the function using an `await` keyword. `await` keyword can be used only inside a `async` function so make the callback into a `async` function.

```
function getUserData() {
   return db.collection('users').get()
        .then( async (querySnapshot) => {
            var docs = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => [doc.data(), doc.id, await getStuff(doc.id)])
            console.log(docs)
            return docs                          
        });
}
```

I haven't tested out my code, but it should work.